# Internet Explorer works only when using VPN

Tags: vpn, internet-explorer

A few days ago I installed an automatic Windows Update and since then Internet Explorer works only when I am connected to the corporate VPN. Obviously I have TCP connectivity and antiviruses and the like still manage to download automatic updates, but I can surf web pages only when I am connected to the corporate VPN. No proxy or static IP is set.

The computer is joined to a corporate domain but in my day to day activities I log on with a local user account. It shouldn't be a router issue since many other colleagues in my office do not have this problem at all. The funny thing however is that there are two other colleagues that have exactly this same problem.

Comment: Ask your IT department to help you, if you're not in the IT department. Read the FAQ if you're not sure why I am suggesting this.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a proxy set in the LAN settings on the connection page?  If teh proxy is only available on the corporate LAN, you would have the issue you have.  This could be set by a Group Policy by the system admin or set manually.